# Can not get a specific valid solution for a simple diophantine equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, gcd-and-lcm

I am working on the following diophantine equation $7x - 5y = -4$ for which I am looking for positive values, specifically that $(x,y) = (3, 5)$. I think I am getting confused with changing signs from the original definition.
My approach:
Using euclidean algorithm we find that: $1 = -2(7) + 3(5)$. Multiplying both sides with $-4$ we get:
$-4 = 8(7) - 12(5)$
This means that we have a solution $(x_0, y_0) = (8, -12)$
The format for all solutions then is:
$x = 8 + n \cdot \frac{lcm(5,7)}{7} = 8 + n \cdot \frac{35}{7} = 8 + 5n$
$y = -12 - n \cdot \frac{lcm(5,7)}{-5} = -12 + n \cdot \frac{35}{-5} = -12 + 7n$

But from these, I can't get $(x,y) = (3,5)$ which is a valid solution to the equation by replacing values for $n$. E.g. for $n = -1$ I get $x = 3$ but $y = -19$
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The correct solution is $(8, 12)$ and generally $(8+5n, 12+7n)$ which gives you $(3,5)$ for $n=-1$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop: Why is it $12$? Isn't the format of the diophantine equation $ax + by = c$?

Comment: Yes, and $a=7, b=-5$. Or, instead of $-4=8(7)-12(5)$ you should've written $-4=8(7)+12(-5)$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop: ah I see. I assigned the minus to the variable instead instead of $b$ and apparently that is wrong. I keep getting confused on changes in variables and substitution. Do you have any recommendation on something to read to help me clear my thinking on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the fact that $-4=8\times7-12\times5$, what you get is that $(8,12)$ is a solution, not $(8,-12)$. And therefore $(8-5,12-7)$ is also a solution. That is, $(3,5)$ is also a solution.

Comment: Why is it $12$? Isn't the format of the diophantine equation $ax + by = c$? I thought the idea is that this format should be kept hence I chose $-12$. It seems that is where my confusion comes from?

Comment: Since your equation is $7x-5y=-4$, and since $7\times8-5\times(-12)=116\ne-4$, it is clear that $(8,-12)$ is *not* a solution. However, $(8,12)$ is, since $7\times8-5\times12=-1$.

Comment: I was thinking it is: $7(8) + (-12)(5) = -4$. I.e. I thought we always consider the format of the equation with positive signs i.e. $ax + by = c$ and any version that has a minus goes to the variables

Comment: I have never been exposed to such a convention and I doubt that it exists.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#Linear_Diophantine_equations "The simplest linear Diophantine equation takes the form ax + by = c, where a, b and c are given integers" so I just thought we are keeping that format and move the signs in the variables

Comment: Then see your equation as $7x+(-12)y=-4$.

Comment: So we never place the minus the variable we seek right? We always place it with the known variables, correct? I often get confused with variable substitutions such as these. Is there anything I can read to help me a bit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128795/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-jim).

Comment: I replied in the chat. I am sorry for the late replies